# Silverlight Plug in Crashes in Video Conference

Tags: silverlight, video, plugins, encoding, crash

We hav developed an application for video conference using silverlight.
It works properly for 15 to 19 min then video get stopped and silverlight plugin has crashed.

for video encoding we r using the JPEG encoder and single image from capturesource get encoded and send on each tick of timer..

I also tried to use Silversuite  but message popup arrives i.e. Silversuite expire

Is der proper solution for encoding or timer or plug in...

Thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we extend the crashing period from 15 min to 1 to 1 n 1/2 hr ......by flushing the mem stream and decreasing the receiving buffer size .....